# How do I add a conditional constraint to GLOP OR-tools?

Tags: c#, or-tools

I'm new to OR-tools, but have used Microsoft's SolverFoundation before.

I'm able to add a standard constraint:

```
solver.Add(sumW2() == sumWeightsMin);
```

where:

```
        LinearExpr sumW2()
        {
            var sum = new LinearExpr();
            for (int i = 0; i < numVars; i++) sum += w[i];
            return sum;
        }
```

but creating conditional constraint (trying to sum only the positive values in this case) doesn't work:

```
    LinearExpr sumW2positive()
    {
        var sum = new LinearExpr();
        for (int i = 0; i < numVars; i++) if(w[i]>0d) sum += w[i].;
        return sum;
    }
```

I get the error:

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Variable' and 'double'

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so many wrong things.

1. you cannot create conditional with a LP solver. You need a mip solver for that.
2. `>` is not defined on variables of a MIP problem because it is ill defined (all solvers work with a small tolerance)
3. I recommend using CP-SAT after reading https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md

Comment: no doubt there are many wrong things, I've never done this before. Thanks I will investigate.